# Refactoring Save User Function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I’m trying to figure out what would be the best route in handling the situation of what would happen if the user is created but then the second insert doesn’t get ran successfully. What are some possibilities?

```
 /**
  * save_user function.
  * 
  * @access public
  * @param string $user_name
  * @param string $user_directory_name
  * @param integer $user_status_id
  * 
  * @return TRUE/FALSE
  */
  public function save_user($user_name, $user_directory_name, $user_status_id)
  {
      $data = array(
         'user_name' => $user_name,
         'user_directory_name' => $user_directory_name,
         'user_status_id' => $user_status_id
      );

      $this->db->insert('users', $data);

      if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
      {
          $data = array(
              'user_id' => $this->db->insert_id()
          );

          $this->db->insert('user_profiles', $data);

          if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
          {
              return true;
          }
          else
          {
              return false;
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: What would be the reasons for the second insert to fail (except a coding error of course)? You could delete the previous line inserted in case of a failure. Or you could look on "transactions" if your database server supports it. That would allow you to perform both inserts but to "commit" them to the database only if both succeeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29). If one of the inserts fails, neither should be allowed to complete. I'm not familiar with codeignighter's db layer. You should check to see if it will automatically issue a rollback if the insert method fails. If not, then you will need to check for these conditions inside your save_user method and either 1) issue the rollback there or 2) return false and handle rollback from the calling code. Also, consult the documentation of the db insert method to see what it returns or whether it throws any exceptions. That may make detecting insert failures much easier than calling affected_rows.